# NGINX proxy_pass to CloudFront with customm domains

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a CloudFront Distribution and I need to do multiple NGINX proxy_pass(es)
for custom domains like described below:

```
aaa.example.com -> https://d2c4fb2vqtbx6f.cloudfront.net/channel/vfc-bcxfhh37u/
bbb.example2.com -> https://d2c4fb2vqtbx6f.cloudfront.net/channel/vfd-gcxiuh47u/
ccc.example3.com -> https://d2c4fb2vqtbx6f.cloudfront.net/channel/voi-j7sfmb09w/
```

I'm getting 403 ERROR from CloudFront unless I'm setting up the Alternate domain name + the Cert. for one of the subdomains above.

Is there any solution for my scenario to use one distribution with multiple domains?

My NGINX is taking care of SSL

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to have a single certificate file containing all the domains and add those domains to CloudFront's Alternate domain name list.

I decided to solve it with a Reverse Proxy (NGINX) and Let'sencrypt (certbot) Here are the steps:

1. Setup an NGINX server to act as a reverse proxy
2. Create a CNAME record pointing to the proxy server from step 1
3. Create a Virtual Host file for the certbot (Let's Encrypt) challenge and restart NGINX (*sudo nginx -s reload*):

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name aaa.example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/$server_name-error.log;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
          root /web/sites/$server_name/www/;
        }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://d2c4fb2vqtbx6f.cloudfront.net/channel/vfc-bcxfhh37u/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
```

4. Created a bash script that will update the certificate:

```
#!/bin/bash

CF_Dist_id=ES70C33IOVC7G
Cert_ARN=arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:723678323458:certificate/48g54dre-5t6b-gf20-9c74-5d6435333dd5
Cert_Name=allcustomdomain
Region=us-east-1 #Certs must remain in us-east-1 regardless of your env. region

#List all existing domains and add them to array
mapfile -t domains  < <(sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/$Cert_Name/cert.pem | openssl x509 -text | grep DNS | tr , '\n' | sed 's/DNS://g' | tr -s ' ')

#Check if cert already exist
if [[ $domains == *"$1"* ]]; then
  echo "Certificate already exists"
  exit 1
fi

#Build domains list for certbot
i=0
while [ $i -le $(("${#domains[@]}"-1)) ];
do
        domainslst="$domainslst -d "${domains[$i]}""
        i=$(($i+1))
done

domainslst="$domainslst -d $1"

echo $domainslst


#Generate certificate
sudo certbot certonly  --expand --nginx  --non-interactive --agree-tos --email me@example.com --cert-name $Cert_Name $domainslst

#Update ACM with new cert
sudo /usr/local/bin/aws acm import-certificate --certificate-arn $Cert_ARN --certificate fileb:///etc/letsencrypt/live/$Cert_Name/cert.pem --private-key fileb:///etc/letsencrypt/live/$Cert_Name/privkey.pem --certificate-chain fileb:///etc/letsencrypt/live/$Cert_Name/fullchain.pem --region $Region


#Get current CloudFront dist config
ETag=$(/usr/local/bin/aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id $CF_Dist_id | jq -r '.ETag')
/usr/local/bin/aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --query 'DistributionConfig' --id $CF_Dist_id > dist.json

#Update the config file with the new custom domain
jq --arg domain $1 '.Aliases.Items += [$domain]' dist.json > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json dist.json
domains_count=$(jq -r '.Aliases.Items | length' dist.json)
echo "Domains count: $domains_count"
jq -r --argjson domains_count "$domains_count" '.Aliases.Quantity = $domains_count' dist.json > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json dist.json

#Update the CloudFront Dist. with the new config.
/usr/local/bin/aws cloudfront   update-distribution --if-match $ETag --id $CF_Dist_id --distribution-config file://dist.json >/dev/null


#remove the config file
rm dist.json
```

5. Save the script as certs.sh
6. Run the script with your new domain, this will generate and import the cert to ACM and update the Dist. with Alt name: *./certs.sh aaa.example.com*
7. Generate the ssl cert for this domain for NGINX use:
   *certbot certonly  --nginx  --non-interactive --agree-tos --email me@example.com -d aaa.example.com*
8. Update the same Virtual Host file from step 3 above with its final config: and restart NGINX (*sudo nginx -s reload*):

```
        server {
          listen 80;
          listen [::]:80;

          server_name aaa.example.com;
          access_log /var/log/nginx/aaa.example.com-access.log;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/aaa.example.com-error.log;
          return 301 https://aaa.example.com$request_uri; # Redirect to https
          }

        server {
          listen 443 ssl http2;
          listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

          server_name aaa.example.com;
          access_log /var/log/nginx/aaa.example.com-ssl-access.log;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/aaa.example.com-ssl-error.log;

          ssl on;
          ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aaa.example.com/fullchain.pem;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aaa.example.com/privkey.pem;
          ssl_session_timeout 5m;
          ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
          ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
          ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
          ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
          ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

          location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
              root /web/sites/aaa.example.com/www/;
          }
          location / {
              proxy_pass https://d2c4fb2vqtbx6f.cloudfront.net/channel/vfc-bcxfhh37u/;
              proxy_set_header host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
              proxy_read_timeout 5m;
              proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
              proxy_set_header Content-Encoding gzip;


          }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Dan, you've just solved a major problem for my company are you still using stack? I'd like to get in touch!